# Pandas - Sum Seperate Frames with Monthly Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([[5,6]], columns=['Jan15','Feb15'])

        Jan15   Feb15
    0   5          6

df_2 = pd.DataFrame([8,3]], columns=['Jan16','Feb16'])

        Jan16   Feb16
    0   8          3
```

Is there a way to sum both frames in order to come out with:

```
sum = Index, Jan, Feb
          0    13   9
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Can you please actually provide more data than 1 row per dataFrame so we can show you a [mcve]?

Comment: Does the solution to this question require more rows? I would hope the solution can be done on multiple frames with only one row.

Comment: No, but it needs a [mcve] that I can copy and paste into an interpreter. Do you only  have these columns? Do you have non-numeric data? I can't know these things for sure unless you tell us explicitly, and taking educated guesses when they turn out wrong only hurts us both.

Comment: The two lines needed to generate these frames was added. Really just trying to determine if two frames with identical rows and columns can be simply summed together in a new frame. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `add()`:

```
df_1.add(df_2)

   Index  Jan15  Feb15
0      0     13      9
```

With different column names:

```
pd.DataFrame(df_1.values + df_2.values, 
             columns = df_1.columns.str.replace("\d", "")).reset_index()
```

Comment: This won't work if the columns are different in the two dataframes, as shown in the OP's example. You'll need to strip out the year info.

Comment: Yep, sorry, was working on previous OP data.  Updating now - feel free to post correct answer if you've already got one prepped.

Comment: Thats fine, simple enough to alter column names. Thank you.

Comment: Updated with a solution that works for different column names.

Comment: Upvoted! Thanks for fixing. However, be careful with this because it does not take order of columns into consideration. Or the fact that one may have more columns than the other.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need `concat` and then a `groupby` on the column headers.

```
pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1).groupby(by=lambda x: x[:3], axis=1).sum()

   Feb  Jan
0    9   13
```

This works on the assumption that your column names all have the format `MTHxx`.

Comment: Nice answer @coldspeed.

Comment: @andrew_reece Thanks! Let me know when you've fixed your answer so I can return the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dummy way of doing this, @coldspeed's answer and @andrew_reece's are the best here:

```
new1 = df_1[:]
new1.columns = [i[:-2] for i in df_1.columns]
new2 = df_2[:]
new2.columns = [i[:-2] for i in df_2.columns]
final_df = new1+new2
indexes = list(new1.index)+list(new1.index)
final_df['Index'] = list(set(indexes))
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
   Jan  Feb  Index
0   13    9      0
```